# How should I approach the implementation of health checks in Azure for my application?

Tags: azure, testing, monitoring, azure-monitoring, health-check

I would like to know how to create health checks for some Azure services? Is this possible? I thought of creating time-triggered Azure functions that would test the end-to-end connectivity of for example my Azure storage, Azure map, and Event Hub but it would fail if suddenly my Azure functions would stop working.
I would like to have some kind of Cachethq, but for all the Azure services that I use for my application.
Is there a best practice for this?

Kind Regards,

Comment: What kind of application do you have, is it a web app?

Comment: @PeterBons I have created a SPA that uses an event hub, azure map, signalR, and azure storage, and more, I would so like to know that everything is running smoothly and thus implement some kind of health checks for my project.

Comment: Does your spa have a backend, like an api?

Comment: @PeterBons Yes, for example, I have a RestAPI that I use to retrieve historical data from my Azure storage via GET.

Comment: While I'm not sure if this type of API is considered as a 'backend'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would have an endpoint that checks any relevant subsytem for errors. This could be a public available /health endpoint. Some frameworks like Asp.Net Core has [built-in support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for health checks.
An http triggered Azure function like you propose could also do the trick.

Then you need something like a watchdog that calls the health endpoint at a given interal. In Azure you can use an [availability test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability). If you want you can create alers based on this availability and create dashboards that show the status over a given period.

If you are hosting your app using Azure Web App you can use the built-in health system as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check)

If you have a load balancer or gateway in front of your app you can use the /health endpoint for health probe endpoints of those balancers/gateways.